# How to make GNU screen create new window on same path under running process (ex: top)

Tags: gnu-screen

I added my `.screenrc` below line to create new window on same path referencing from
[How can I make GNU Screen start a new window at the CURRENT working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517414/how-can-i-make-gnu-screen-start-a-new-window-at-the-current-working-directory)

```
bind , stuff "screen^M" #send command 'screen' to current screen session
```

It creates new window on current path well.
However if it some process is running (ex. `top`), the new screen command cannot pass to current session, so it fails.

Is there any way to avoid this situation.
When I compile a source, It takes long times so I can not make new window (with same path) by this method.

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions.

Comment: Please, ask the question at [unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I learned from this method in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517414/how-can-i-make-gnu-screen-start-a-new-window-at-the-current-working-directory